# How do I know if the data split thas been done before or after my scaler with scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am creating a decision tree model using scikit-learn and I need to split the data **BEFORE** scaling them using `StandardScaler()`. However, I also want to use the `cross_val_score()` method.

I first encoded some of my categorical data using `OneHotEncoding()` within `make_column_transformer()` as below:

```
transformer = sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer(
            (sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), ['SoilDrainage', 'Geology', 'LU2016']),
            remainder='passthrough')
```

I then instantiate my model and scaler class:

```
model = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

scalar = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()
```

I add them to my pipeline:

```
pipe = sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline(transformer, scalar, model)
```

Finally, I input the pipeline into `cross_val_score()`:

```
sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy').mean()
```

I don't get any errors when I do this but because the split is done within the `cross_val_score()` method I'm not sure how to verify if the scaler is applied before or after the data has been split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf0ea25d/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L381

If you look at the documentation for `_fit_and_score()`, it is explicitly written that the estimator (=your pipeline) is applied only on the splits of the dataset.

Furthermore, in `cross_validate()`, the estimator is cloned for each split.

Comment: So does that mean its the same for 'cross_val_score()' or are you suggesting I use '_fit_and_score()' instead?

Comment: `cross_val_score` uses `_fit_and_score`, (an underscore in front of a function or variable indicates that it is an internal mechanism of a function). The split does take place before your pipeline is applied.

Comment: Great, that makes sense, thanks. My final question is, does the use of StandardScaler() result in training to (the functions version of) 'X_train' and fitting to both 'X_train' and 'X_test' or do I have to use 'StandardScaler.fit()' and 'StandardScaler.transform()' to do that manually? Thanks for your help

Comment: If I refer to section 3.11 "Data transformation with held out data" (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), the scaler is only fit on X_train and transform on X_test.